# How to get a particular row of data from data base on Listview click?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-edittext

How to get a particular row of data from data base on Listview click?And set that data in edittext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without context it can be tricky to answer but here are some elements that may help you.

First you need to bind every element in your listview with a specific row index. This can be achieved either by using the position of the clicked item in the list (position = row) or by using the content display (tag, id, ...) to find the appropriate row in your database.

Then you can display the result data, as well as the EditText in a popup dialog. If you want the EditText to replace the data already displayed in the view, this can be a bit more complex though.